# Class Not Found on Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello  i came across to this tutorial

http://www.dunebook.com/learn-how-to-import-data-from-csv-using-eloquent-in-laravel/

I create what is on tutorial

Migration

so i create a model

Scifi.php

```
class Scifi extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'scifi';
}
```

on my routes.php

```
Route::get('csv', function()
{
    if (($handle = fopen(public_path() .. '/scifi.csv','r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !==FALSE)
        {
                $scifi = new Scifi();
                $scifi->character = $data[0];
                $scifi->movie = $data[1];
                $scifi->save();
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    return Scifi::all();
});
```

But when i access it

localhost/laravelcsv/public/csv

I get this error

```
FatalErrorException in routes.php line 14:Class 'Scifi' not found
```

Comment: Also running `composer dump-autoload` may be required after changing the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the namespace. Replace `Scifi` by `App\Scifi`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a namespace for **Scifi** class:

use **App\Scifi;**  statement in routes.php:

Answer (score 0):

You are not referring the name space for your model file in your controller. So please refer your model.

```
use App\Scifi;
```

If you are using `Scifi` model in `App\Model` folder,

```
use App\Model\Scifi;
```

Answer (score 0):

class is not found an error in Laravel :
to solve this problem you just add `use App\Scifi` on top
directory/className